# Как валидировать форму на чистом css при помощи псевдоклассов invalid и placeholder-shown?

Tags: css, css3, валидация, форма

Прочитал в [статье](https://habr.com/ru/post/332804/), что можно валидировать форму на чистом CSS используя сочетание псевдоклассов `:placeholder-shown` и `:invalid` и свойства `:not`.
Пробую воспроизвести это в форме ниже, но не получается добиться результата.
Валидацию в самом примере тоже не получается проверить

```css
.form {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.form__field {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.validation {
  color: red;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3px;
  display: none;
}

.form input {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:valid:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  border-color: green;
}

input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  border-color: red;
}

input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown)+.validation {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form">
  <div class="form__field">
    <label>*Фамилия 
    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder=" " required>
    <span class="validation">Поле обязательно к заполнению.</span>               </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form__field">
    <label>*Имя              
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" " required>
    <span class="validation">Поле обязательно к заполнению.</span>               </label>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button type="submit">Отправить обращение</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `required=""`  `required` (это булевый атрибут). И что собственно не устраивает, в чем суть проблемы? Раскрой фразы _«не получается добиться результата»_ и _«не получается проверить»_, допиши в вопрос подробности о затруднениях с которыми столкнулся.

Comment: @yar85 это поправил, но на результат не повлияло

Comment: Результат сейчас соответствует тому что написано, поэтому и нужны подробности в вопросе :) Если ты про красную обводку - то ее быть не должно,  ибо в селекторе условие непоказа плейсхолдера и условие невалидности (в данном случае, невалидным поле может быть только если пустое) взаимоисключают друг друга. Такой селектор может работать разве что с заполненным атрибутом `pattern`, но в верстке он отсутствует. Если же хочешь видеть красную обводку у пустых полей, то убери из селектора c `:invalid` условие "непоказа" плейсхолдера `:not(:placeholder-shown)`.

Comment: @yar85 в моём случае обводка не используется. Я хочу добиться того, чтобы при попытке отправки пустого поля всплывало красная надпись ` <span class="validation">Поле обязательно к заполнению.</span>`

Comment: У правила показа `.validation` проблема та же самая, о которой я написал комментарием выше: взаимоисключающие условия в селекторе. _В данном случае_, поле ввода невалидно **тогда и только тогда**, когда оно пусто. А когда поле ввода пусто, показывается плейсхолдер. В селекторе фактически написано условие "невалидно (пусто) **И** без плейсхолдера (не пусто)" => это условие, которое никогда не выполнится.

Comment: _«чтобы при попытке отправки пустого поля всплывало красная надпись»_ - увы, такое невозможно реализовать одними лишь стилями... стили позволят сделать только постоянное присутствие красной надписи когда поле невалидно (другими словами, стили применяются даже если пользователь вообще не трогал форму). Чтобы именно при отправке проверялась валидность (а до этого не проверялась) - такое можно сделать только при помощи скрипта, т.е. средствами JS.

Comment: @yar85 в статье рассматривался лайфхак, когда в плейсхолдере стоит только пробел `placeholder=" "`, т.е. для пользователя как будто пусто, но на самом деле нет. Но, в силу того, что пример из статьи не удаётся воспроизвести, чтобы протестировать этот момент и возник данный топик с вопросом

Comment: В примере из статьи используется атрибут `type` со специальными значениями (`tel`, `url`, и так далее) - это является альтернативой использованию атрибута `pattern` с шаблоном проверки. А в разметке из вопроса, эти атрибуты не используются. В том и причина "невоспроизводимости", равно как и причиной логического противоречия в условиях селекторов. То есть, проблема только в том что разметка и стили набраны без даже грамма понимания. Эта проблема решается изучением, вместо "игр вслепую" с версткой. Почитай про атрибут `type` на MDN, это должно помочь.

Comment: Вот кстати, в том и беда ссылок в вопросах - по ним мало кто ходит (вот я только сейчас перешел посмотреть, что там за статья... а другие наверное вообще не переходили, раз ответов нет). Вопрос должен содержать всю информацию в своем тексте, а не ссылками на сторонние ресурсы - самодостаточность вопросов полезна и их авторам, и сообществу. При этом, все подчистую копировать конечно не надо, достаточно только самой сути и _буквального_ воспроизведения (типа: "задача <такая то>; вот <исходный пример> который работает, и вот <мой пример> который не работает"). Это не сложно ведь...